# JSON.NET - Select All Objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am looking for a method to select ALL the objects in the `JObject` using Json.NET. So in short, if I had the following JSON:

```
{
  "someCar" : {
    "id" : "3",
    "model" : "M7",
    "engine" : "FI V8",
  },
  "name" : "carparkone",
  "id" : "1",
  "cars" : [
    {
      "id" : "1",
      "model" : "s60",
      "engine" : "i5",
    },
    {
      "id" : "2",
      "model" : "m3",
      "engine" : "FI V6",
    },
    {
      "id" : "3",
      "model" : "M7",
      "engine" : "FI V8",
    }
  ]
}
```

I would run some command to get an array of all the objects in it, i.e. anything in `{}` blocks.

Ideally, I would find all the objects where `someProp` has `some value`, so only objects that have a property `engine` with a value of `V6`.

**tl;dr the question:**

1. How do I get a list of ALL objects nested in JObject?
2. (Bonus) only get objects with specific properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse and filter JSON objects when there is no predefined schema.

First, parse your JSON to a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) using [`JToken.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm).  Then you can use [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm) to iterate through that root object, and all descendant tokens of it, in document order.  (Or use [`JContainer.Descendants()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Descendants.htm) if you want to skip the root object.)  Then you can filter then using using [`.OfType<JObject>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) to return all objects whether nested or not:

```
var root = JObject.Parse(jsonString;
var allObjs = root.DescendantsAndSelf()
    .OfType<JObject>()
    .ToArray();
```

To filter by some value, you can add an additional [`Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) clause as shown in the following extension method:

```
public static partial class JTokenExtensions
{
    public static JObject [] FilterObjects<T>(this JObject root, string someProp, T someValue)
    {
        var comparer = new JTokenEqualityComparer();
        var someValueToken = JToken.FromObject(someValue);
        var objs = root.DescendantsAndSelf()
            .OfType<JObject>()
            .Where(t => comparer.Equals(t[someProp], someValueToken))
            .ToArray();

        return objs;
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
var filteredObjs = root.FilterObjects(someProp, someValue);
```

To make `FilterObjects()` be completely generic, I serialize the desired value to a `JToken` then use [`JTokenEqualityComparer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenEqualityComparer.htm) to compare the actual value with the desired value.  If you know that the desired value is a primitive type, instead you can do:

```
public static partial class JTokenExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNull(this JToken token)
    {
        return token == null || token.Type == JTokenType.Null;
    }

    public static JObject[] FilterObjectsSimple<T>(this JObject root, string someProp, T someValue)
    {
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        var objs = root.DescendantsAndSelf()
            .OfType<JObject>()
            .Where(t => { var v = t[someProp]; return v != null && (someValue == null ? v.IsNull() : comparer.Equals(v.ToObject<T>(), someValue)); })
            .ToArray();

        return objs;
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GhctrP).

Note - you might also consider using [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm), which supports the [JSONPath query syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), e.g.:

```
var someProp = "id";
var someValue = "3";
var filterString = string.Format(@"..*[?(@.{0} == '{1}')]", someProp, someValue);
var filteredObjs = root.SelectTokens(filterString).ToArray();
```

However, your JSON includes objects nested directly inside other objects, and Newtonsoft's implementation of JSONPath does not find such directly nested objects, as explained in [JSONPath scripts not executing correctly for objects #1256](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1256).

Comment: I ended up using jsonpath, ty for the caveat.

Answer (score 4):

You model your data like this:

```
public class Carpark {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cars")]
    public IEnumerable<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "model")]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "engine")]
    public string Engine { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the model to Deserialize your string using [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

```
var carpark = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Carpark>(myJsonString);

foreach(var car in carpark.Cars.Where(c => c.Engine.ToLower().Contains("v6"))
    Console.WriteLine(car.Model);
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. The problem is that I can have "cars" nested anywhere in the json structure, so I really need to check all objects, anywhere in the json, if possible.

Comment: JSON is for structured and predictable communication over the web.  If your "cars" object could be anywhere, then it's not JSON. :)

Comment: I was promised space magic by my co-worker. Promises of space magic never lie... Anyway, ty for the response, I am going to spend a bit more time looking for the magic answer and come back to accept yours if my search is in vain.